# How to return 401 page instead of login page when logged in user doesn't have permission , cookies asp.net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

if the user try to access a role based restricted controller is send to login,
I would like to redirect already authorized users to a certain page  while the unauthorized users  would be redirected to login.

Comment: Consider redirecting both to the certain page. Then the certain page can check if they are authorized, and if they aren't redirect them to the login page.